# Set ApplicationBarIconButton color to Black in both Dark and Light Themes

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm working on Windows Phone 8 apps where my need is to set the `ApplicationBarIconButton` to `Black` in both Dark or Light themes of Windows Phone. I want to use Default Application Bar of Windows Phone, don't want to replace it with some custom controls.

Why Need this? Because I want a `ApplicationBar` whose opacity is set to 0, now colour of my `ApplicationBarIconButton` is automatically set to White as my default theme is Dark, because of that my Icons are not visible properly so that I want to use only Black colour of IconButton for both themes.

Any useful answers are appreciated. A big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `ForegroundColor` of the ApplicationBar to be `Black` (or any other colour). This will override the default theme colours.

```
<shell:ApplicationBar ForegroundColor="Black" Opacity="0">
    <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/AppBar/myIcon.png" IsEnabled="True" Text="button"  />
</shell:ApplicationBar>
```

Comment: But I want to set `ApplicationBar` Opacity property to 0 which means I want transaparent `ApplicationBar`

Comment: You can still set the opacity to 0, I've updated the answer to include it. I assumed you had that part set and was just showing how to force a black foreground colour.